# OSX: programmatically implementing Undo for variables other than NSObject

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, cocoa

Here's the scenario: my program is dealing with a variable-size one-dimensional array of float values (it's **not** an ***NSObject***, but a standard **C** float*), which can get modified (both in size and in content) by the program. Is there a way to programmatically implement **undo** features like putting the entire **array** contents and its **size** on the undo stack and having them recalled (reverted) if the user is not satisfied with the last modification? Thanks in advance?

Comment: What class controls that array? What modifies it? That's the object that would have the relevant methods to restore its state, and invocations of those would go on the undo stack.

Comment: It's the **NSApplicationDelegate** and few of its instance interface-implementation methods, AFAICT, thanks